# Javascript fails while trying to declare nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a jQuery based simple mail template system. It is basically a nested array which is supposed to look like:

```
templates[1] = {
                    "name":"product damage claim",
                    "def":{
                        {'Customer Name?','delivery_name',1},
                        {'Date by which information should be provided by customer?','',1},
                        {'Order ID','orders_id',0}
                    },
                    "tpl":'Mail Content goes here'
};
```

Now if I write the above, javascript fails. It seems, I am doing something wrong in defining the `def` object, any idea what?

Comment: fails in what sense? Give us the error

Comment: What is this: `{'Customer Name?','delivery_name',1}` ? That's neither an `Object` nor an `Array`

Comment: object is key:value, not key,value

Comment: You should learn the basic syntax! lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `def` contains a list of values, it should be an array of arrays

```
templates[1] = {
    "name": "product damage claim",
        "def": [
        ['Customer Name?', 'delivery_name', 1],
        ['Date by which information should be provided by customer?', '', 1],
        ['Order ID', 'orders_id', 0]
    ],
        "tpl": 'Mail Content goes here'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want a simple list of values, you need an **array**:

```
"def": [
   ['Customer Name?','delivery_name',1],
   ['Date by which information should be provided by customer?','',1],
   ['Order ID','orders_id',0]
],
```

Now, that'll fix your syntactic problems, but that arrangement doesn't make it particularly easy to extract the stuff stored in the object.